# android latest OS version to which a device can be upgraded

Tags: android, operating-system

How can we know what is the latest version of OS that can a device be upgraded to.
I have samsung GT19100 with android2.3.3

I want to know if this can be upgraded to android 4

How can we know this for any other device model

Comment: No technical way. All depends on device manufacturer decisions to (not) issue upgrades for specific device, even if device hardware allows such upgrade.

Comment: No way to know for all phones, but I happen to know that the Galaxy S2 is supposed to get ICS sometime before April. (Google for '"Galaxy S2" + ICS')

Comment: Thanks to all of u, all the comments were really helpful. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Technically if your phone runs gingerbread then you should be able to run ICS. I think the base spec is like 512mb ram and 1ghz cpu, but I'm not too sure, you should look into that.

Your phone will be able to run it. HOWEVER whether your carrier/manufacturer pushes an update is completely different. It may be worth joining a website like xda-developers.com and seeing if there are any 3rd party builds that you can put on your phone (eg: cyanogenmod9).

Hope this helps.